# Accessing a value from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, visual-studio

Hi I'm trying to learn python. I'm trying to get the exchange rate of USD to AUD.
But I'm struggling to access the information from the JSON stored in data.
How would I go about getting "AUD": 1.4817 in "conversion_rates":

```
# Where USD is the base currency you want to use
    url = 'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/MY_API_KEY/latest/USD'
# Making our request
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
```

This is what is being stored in data

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "documentation": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
    "terms_of_use": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
    "time_last_update_unix": 1585267200,
    "time_last_update_utc": "Fri, 27 Mar 2020 00:00:00 +0000",
    "time_next_update_unix": 1585353700,
    "time_next_update_utc": "Sat, 28 Mar 2020 00:00:00 +0000",
    "base_code": "USD",
    "conversion_rates": {
        "USD": 1,
        "AUD": 1.4817,
        "BGN": 1.7741,
        "CAD": 1.3168,
        "CHF": 0.9774,
        "CNY": 6.9454,
        "EGP": 15.7361,
        "EUR": 0.9013,
        "GBP": 0.7679,
        "...": 7.8536,
        "...": 1.3127,
        "...": 7.4722, etc. etc.
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `data['conversion_rates']['AUD']`

Comment: Good day @rdas I tried that and got this aud Exception occurred during evaluation. Using this  aud = data['conversion_rates']['AUD']

Comment: Nevermind thank you my issue was i was trying to print aud forgot to cast it to a string

Answer (score 4):

`response.json()` returns a the json-data as a `dict`. You can access a dict whether via `dict[key]` or `dict.get(key, default)`. The first one throws an exception if the key is not found. The second one returns default None if the key is not found or the default value you gave to the `get`-call.

So in your case it would be:

```py
data['conversion_rates']['AUD']
```

or e.g.

```py
data.get('conversion_rates', default={}).get('AUD')
```

You probably want to choose the first opportunity, and surround it with a try/catch:

```py
try:
    aud_conversion_rate = data['conversion_rates']['AUD']
except KeyError:
    print("Could not get the USD to AUD conversion rate")
```

For reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thank you probably best i try something like that

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get all the values that you need by keys.

```
converstion_rates = data['conversion_rates']
USD = converstion_rates['USD']
AUD = converstion_rates['AUD']
```

Please see this doc:
[Python- Json data](https://realpython.com/python-json/)

Answer (score 1):

The parsed response to your request is a dictionary in python. You can see it as the print out ist written with curly brackets.
A dictionary consists of key value pairs. In the written output separated bei colon. You can access one entry by indexing, as follows:

```
data["conversion rates"]
```

In your case this is again a dictionary. So proceed as described.